# CSS HTML Navigation Menu

Tags: html, css, navigation

This example has a ul navigation at the top left that is fixed,
it represents 4 sections; each containing a variable 
amount of text.  I want to know how to manage the HTML/CSS 
so that whatever section is clicked (1-4) the relevant text for that 
section is brought to the top regardless of the amount of text in any 
section.  In other words, whatever section is clicked - that section is
brought up to the exact same position in the window.  So the navigation
menu is fixed and when clicked the corresponding section of text is brought
to the same exact position and in view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

body 
{
    background-color:#F3E2A9;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    font-size: 14px;  
    font-weight: normal;  
    font-variant: normal;  
    font-style: normal;  
    line-height: 120%;  
    margin:200px 0px 0px 250px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    max-width:600px;
}  


            #navlist
            {
            position: fixed;
            left: 50px; /**/
            top: 75px;
            }

            #navlist
            {
            padding-left: 0;
            margin-left: 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
            width: 150px;
            }

            #navlist li
            {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0.25em;
            border-top: 1px solid gray;
            }


#navlist li a 
{
line-height: 125%;  
text-decoration: none; 
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
font-variant:small-caps;

font-style: bold;  

}


        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>



        </ul>


<a id="1"</a>
<h2>1</h2>
<p>
1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sonet molestie an qui, cum iriure evertitur concludaturque ne, inani utamur at duo. Usu ludus 

inermis molestie ut. Case doctus definitiones vis ex, mea ut habemus persequeris, vidit idque nec at. Ne eos nobis senserit 

voluptatum, eruditi invenire ius an, posse munere sed ea. Mea reque dicunt electram an, per veniam consul virtute cu. Ad mel 

harum aliquam instructior, nobis soluta omnium ad sea.

</p>

<a id="2"</a>
<h2>2</h2>
<p>
2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sonet molestie an qui, cum iriure evertitur concludaturque ne, inani utamur at duo. Usu ludus 

inermis molestie ut. Case doctus definitiones vis ex, mea ut habemus persequeris, vidit idque nec at. Ne eos nobis senserit 

voluptatum, eruditi invenire ius an, posse munere sed ea. Mea reque dicunt electram an, per veniam consul virtute cu. Ad mel 

harum aliquam instructior, nobis soluta omnium ad sea.

2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sonet molestie an qui, cum iriure evertitur concludaturque ne, inani utamur at duo. Usu ludus 

inermis molestie ut. Case doctus definitiones vis ex, mea ut habemus persequeris, vidit idque nec at. Ne eos nobis senserit 

voluptatum, eruditi invenire ius an, posse munere sed ea. Mea reque dicunt electram an, per veniam consul virtute cu. Ad mel 

harum aliquam instructior, nobis soluta omnium ad sea.
2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sonet molestie an qui, cum iriure evertitur concludaturque ne, inani utamur at duo. Usu ludus 

inermis molestie ut. Case doctus definitiones vis ex, mea ut habemus persequeris, vidit idque nec at. Ne eos nobis senserit 

voluptatum, eruditi invenire ius an, posse munere sed ea. Mea reque dicunt electram an, per veniam consul virtute cu. Ad mel 

harum aliquam instructior, nobis soluta omnium ad sea.
2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sonet molestie an qui, cum iriure evertitur concludaturque ne, inani utamur at duo. Usu ludus 

inermis molestie ut. Case doctus definitiones vis ex, mea ut habemus persequeris, vidit idque nec at. Ne eos nobis senserit 

voluptatum, eruditi invenire ius an, posse munere sed ea. Mea reque dicunt electram an, per veniam consul virtute cu. Ad mel 

harum aliquam instructior, nobis soluta omnium ad sea.

2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sonet molestie an qui, cum iriure evertitur concludaturque ne, inani utamur at duo. Usu ludus 

inermis molestie ut. Case doctus definitiones vis ex, mea ut habemus persequeris, vidit idque nec at. Ne eos nobis senserit 

voluptatum, eruditi invenire ius an, posse munere sed ea. Mea reque dicunt electram an, per veniam consul virtute cu. Ad mel 

harum aliquam instructior, nobis soluta omnium ad sea.
2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sonet molestie an qui, cum iriure evertitur concludaturque ne, inani utamur at duo. Usu ludus 

inermis molestie ut. Case doctus definitiones vis ex, mea ut habemus persequeris, vidit idque nec at. Ne eos nobis senserit 

voluptatum, eruditi invenire ius an, posse munere sed ea. Mea reque dicunt electram an, per veniam consul virtute cu. Ad mel 

harum aliquam instructior, nobis soluta omnium ad sea.

2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sonet molestie an qui, cum iriure evertitur concludaturque ne, inani utamur at duo. Usu ludus 

inermis molestie ut. Case doctus definitiones vis ex, mea ut habemus persequeris, vidit idque nec at. Ne eos nobis senserit 

voluptatum, eruditi invenire ius an, posse munere sed ea. Mea reque dicunt electram an, per veniam consul virtute cu. Ad mel 

harum aliquam instructior, nobis soluta omnium ad sea.
2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sonet molestie an qui, cum iriure evertitur concludaturque ne, inani utamur at duo. Usu ludus 

inermis molestie ut. Case doctus definitiones vis ex, mea ut habemus persequeris, vidit idque nec at. Ne eos nobis senserit 

voluptatum, eruditi invenire ius an, posse munere sed ea. Mea reque dicunt electram an, per veniam consul virtute cu. Ad mel 

harum aliquam instructior, nobis soluta omnium ad sea.


</p>
<a id="3"</a>
<h2>3</h2>
<p>
3Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sonet molestie an qui, cum iriure evertitur concludaturque ne, inani utamur at duo. Usu ludus  
 Quis fuisset ut has, in sit vero probo, vim in elit inermis expetendis. At veniam nullam eleifend pri. Mel in nusquam conceptam 

referrentur, eos et natum insolens vituperata. In sea alia eruditi, ceteros vivendo est ad. Wisi dicam atomorum eu duo. Quo 

primis dignissim intellegat ex.


</p>
<a id="4"</a>
<h2>4</h2>
<p>
4Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sonet molestie an qui, cum iriure evertitur concludaturque ne, inani utamur at duo. Usu ludus 

inermis molestie ut. Case doctus definitiones vis ex, mea ut habemus persequeris, vidit idque nec at. Ne eos nobis senserit 

voluptatum, eruditi invenire ius an, posse munere sed ea. Mea reque dicunt electram an, per veniam consul virtute cu. Ad mel 

harum aliquam instructior, nobis soluta omnium ad sea.

</p>
<a id="5"</a>
<h2>5</h2>
<p>
5Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sonet molestie an qui, cum iriure evertitur concludaturque ne, inani utamur at duo. Usu ludus 

inermis molestie ut. Case doctus definitiones vis ex, mea ut habemus persequeris, vidit idque nec at. Ne eos nobis senserit 

voluptatum, eruditi invenire ius an, posse munere sed ea. Mea reque dicunt electram an, per veniam consul virtute cu. Ad mel 

harum aliquam instructior, nobis soluta omnium ad sea.

</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note: IDs [***should not***](http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/2065702) start with numbers as they can only be reached by using `[id="1"]` in CSS (`#1` will not work)

Comment: @ZachSaucier hmmm... interesting, have you actually tried that? See my answer, I used (almost) the exact same code as above, and there is no problem at all with using `#1` - you might want to elaborate on why it wouldn't work, or is it just incorrect markup...?

Comment: @webeno 1. It is incorrect markup 2. It cannot be reached by using the CSS styling: `#1 { ... properties ... }`, which you did not do

Comment: @ZachSaucier both may be true, though by you saying it doesn't work, it implied it wouldn't work for linking to sections of a page which is of course untrue, because it does, which I believe was the purpose of them in this question.

Comment: @webeno It's irrelevant to your the answer of this question but is still incorrect HTML - thus I pointed it out in a comment on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a larger bottom margin, one that will definitely overlap the page once the page scrolls up when the menu items are clicked

```
body {
    /* ... */
    margin:200px 0px 2000px 250px;
    /* ... */
}
```

Additionally, you can apply a top padding to `h2` so that it appears exactly at the height you want it:

```
h2 {    
    padding-top:95px
}
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/59V5z/1/) (I cleaned up your code a little bit)

Comment: webeno - sorry I was trying to fiddle up my issue and the comment posted prematurely - then I had to move on to something else.  But if you look at the original fiddle with:  
h2 {    
    padding-top:95px
}

Comment: erm... think you didn't finish your sentence or I still don't understand what you mean...